# 0.f / 123u / etc. в инициализации

Tags: c++, c, стандарт, литерал

Замечал код вроде:

```
float var = 0.3f;
uint16_t var2 = 123u;
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что значит f, u.
Догадываюсь, что это - некие квалификаторы, но где про них можно почитать подробнее?
Есть ли резон их использования?Как я полагаю, при инициализации нет приведения типов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float var = 0.3f;
```

Инициализируем значением 0.3 **типа float** (без f это было бы значение типа double).

```
uint16_t var2 = 123u;
```

Инициализируем значением 123 **типа unsigned int** (без u это было бы значение типа int).

Естественно, при инициализации точно так же при необходимости выполняется приведение типов, как и при обычном присваивании, например.

Прочесть об этом можно в разделе 5.13 "Литералы" стандарта С++. Например, [тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#nt:integer-suffix) и [тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.fcon#nt:floating-point-suffix).

Comment: Для явного определения числа как short литерала, как я понял, нет?

Comment: Да, в стандарте его нет, но вполне допускаю, что в каких-то компиляторах имеется соответствующее расширение.